# MariaDB not caching queries that MySQL does?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm migrating my database (MySQL 5.1.73) to a new server, and I am trying to replace it with mariadb (5.5.5-10). Globally mariadb seems much faster, but there is a couple of queries that it refuses to cache where mysql does.
This is a big problem because those queries are used LOTS (there are sort of on the home page so will be executed pretty much every time the user interact).

I thought mariadb was a drop in replacement for mysql, so I'm surprised of this behavior ? As anyone any idea why such a different behavior or how can I force the cache to be used (I tried `SELECT SQL_CACHE` but that doesn't change anything.

Here is the mysql configuration

```
    +------------------------------+------------+
    | Variable_name                | Value      |
    +------------------------------+------------+
    | binlog_cache_size            | 32768      |
    | have_query_cache             | YES        |
    | key_cache_age_threshold      | 300        |
    | key_cache_block_size         | 1024       |
    | key_cache_division_limit     | 100        |
    | max_binlog_cache_size        | 4294963200 |
    | query_cache_limit            | 1048576    |
    | query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096       |
    | query_cache_size             | 16777216   |
    | query_cache_type             | ON         |
    | query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF        |
    | table_definition_cache       | 256        |
    | table_open_cache             | 64         |
    | thread_cache_size            | 8          |
    +------------------------------+------------+
```

And the mariadb one

```
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name                  | Value                |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
| aria_pagecache_age_threshold   | 300                  |
| aria_pagecache_buffer_size     | 134217728            |
| aria_pagecache_division_limit  | 100                  |
| aria_pagecache_file_hash_size  | 512                  |
| binlog_cache_size              | 32768                |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size         | 32768                |
| have_query_cache               | YES                  |
| host_cache_size                | 228                  |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache | OFF                  |
| innodb_ft_cache_size           | 8000000              |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit   | 2000000000           |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size     | 640000000            |
| join_cache_level               | 2                    |
| key_cache_age_threshold        | 300                  |
| key_cache_block_size           | 1024                 |
| key_cache_division_limit       | 100                  |
| key_cache_file_hash_size       | 512                  |
| key_cache_segments             | 0                    |
| max_binlog_cache_size          | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size     | 18446744073709547520 |
| metadata_locks_cache_size      | 1024                 |
| query_cache_limit              | 1048576              |
| query_cache_min_res_unit       | 4096                 |
| query_cache_size               | 16777216             |
| query_cache_strip_comments     | OFF                  |
| query_cache_type               | ON                   |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate   | OFF                  |
| stored_program_cache           | 256                  |
| table_definition_cache         | 400                  |
| table_open_cache               | 400                  |
| thread_cache_size              | 100                  |
+--------------------------------+----------------------+
```

### Update

The query :

```
SELECT sum(amount) AS amount
       ,ADDDATE( SUBDATE( tran_date
                        , DAYOFMONTH(tran_date)-1
                        )
               , INTERVAL  12 MONTH
               ) AS trans_date
FROM 0_gl_trans
WHERE account IN (1100) AND amount < 0 
      AND (tran_date > '2010-10-26' AND tran_date < '2015-10-26')
GROUP BY trans_date
```

Comment: Are your queries doing anything "special"? It's hard to determine why the queries aren't cached without the actual explains etc. Also mariadb 5.5/10 are compatible with mysql 5.5. So maybe you're hitting some backward compatibility issues (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/)

Comment: The difference in behavior is likely the difference in the MySQL version (5.1 vs. 5.5.) A query cannot be cached if it references a user-defined variable, a stored function, a non-deterministic function, a partitioned table, et al. So one first step would be to verify that the query is actually eligible to be cached... https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/query-cache/#queries-stored-in-the-query-cache

Comment: The query has nothing special, just a few function and a group by (see update). However, explain shows that it needs a temporary table, not sure if that do anything.

Comment: "A query will not be added to the cache if ... It uses TEMPORARY table"

Comment: The query doesn't use temporaty table, it's just mariadb which uses them. Does that count ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153384/mariadb-not-caching-queries-cached-by-mysql .

Comment: Add this composite: `INDEX(account, tran_date)`; maybe it will run so fast you won't notice the difference.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on both servers; I suspect there will be a difference.

Comment: If the database name has any special characters and the engine is InnoDB, the QC won't work in older versions of MySQL.  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55556